# sticky div fixed position

Tags: html, css, css-position, sticky

Here is my html work. http://jsfiddle.net/awaises/remqf/4/

I want to push the fixed `div` box to bottom of the screen. But it is overlapping on the left navigation and last items of the navigation getting hide behind the green box. Can we fix the green box as per following design? But we have to make sure that green box must be at the bottom of the screen even window’s resolution is small or large.

Design layout URL
http://www.thewebmakerz.com/screen.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Does this `.left-col{ height:500px;}` fix your problem?

Comment: No, i can't fix the left-col height because left navigation item will be control by admin and can be added more items in near future.

Answer (score 0):

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9Hu6x/).

Three key tips:

1. Put "left-footer" in a different parent then your menu content (called "left-col-top").
2. "left-col-top" should be transparent, "position:fixed", with "z-index:1" and a min-height that is taller than your menu.
3. "left-footer" should be "position:absolute."

Comment: No, still same problem. If i add more items in left col, they are hiding behind the green box. Green box still overlapping :(

Answer (score 0):

Looking at screen 1.1, if there is 11th list in yellow box, it will definitely go behind green box. (Also consider toolbars / menu bars in browsers). You may have to use something like "More Links >" in case height of screen is less.

Screen 1.2 and onwards:
If jQuery is an option, you can use scrollTop function.
Initially, let the green-box be fixed with position:fixed and some margin negative from bottom.
Then, when user scrolls to a particular amount (as seen in screen 1.2) try following jQuery code:

```
var yellowBoxHeight = $("div.yellow-box").height();
$document.scroll(function() {
  if ($document.scrollTop() >= yellowBoxHeight - 100) {
    // If user has scrolled some amount, eg. 100 pixels of yellow box is still visible
    // make the green box animate & let it come upwards
  } else {
   // put the green-box back with some negative margin into the bottom
  }
});
```